# scrape the anglelist data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= requests.get('https://angel.co/companies').text
soup= BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="name"):
    print(div.text)
```

I want to print the name of company list but it print nothing.

Comment: As the content of that website is loaded dynamically, requests won't be able to catch that unless you perform a `post` requests with their api. You have to choose any browser simulator like selenium to get the content of that webpage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1637-Dubai,+AE')
time.sleep(10)
soup= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
name_data = []
for item in soup.select('.name'):
    name=item.text.strip()
    name_data.append(name)
    print(name)


driver.quit()
```

It works fine